# XML dump of MySQL database don't include foreign key constraints. What can be the reason? sqldump(.sql) file list it

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, xml, mysqladmin

I am accessing schema information of databases in XML format. I am taking dump of the database in XML format using the command below.

**mysqldump --no-data --xml -u root -p bakerydb > bakerydb.xml**

these dump don't list the foreign key constraints. Below part of the output is listed.

```
   <table_structure name="class_details">
        <field Field="id" Type="int(10)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" Comment="" />
        <field Field="course_id" Type="int(10)" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="start_date" Type="date" Null="NO" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="end_date" Type="date" Null="NO" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="tutor_id" Type="int(10)" Null="NO" Key="MUL" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <key Table="class_details" Non_unique="0" Key_name="PRIMARY" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="id" Collation="A" Cardinality="0" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="class_details" Non_unique="1" Key_name="fk_cources_offered_class_details" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="course_id" Collation="A" Cardinality="0" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <key Table="class_details" Non_unique="1" Key_name="fk_employee_details_class_details" Seq_in_index="1" Column_name="tutor_id" Collation="A" Cardinality="0" Null="" Index_type="BTREE" Comment="" Index_comment="" />
        <options Name="class_details" Engine="InnoDB" Version="10" Row_format="Compact" Rows="0" Avg_row_length="0" Data_length="16384" Max_data_length="0" Index_length="32768" Data_free="7340032" Auto_increment="1" Create_time="2014-02-25 07:08:56" Collation="utf8_general_ci" Create_options="" Comment="" />
    </table_structure>
```

Same database lists the detailed foreign key constraint in sqldump. (.sql file).
below that's mentioned.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class_details`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `class_details` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `tutor_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_cources_offered_class_details` (`course_id`),
  KEY `fk_employee_details_class_details` (`tutor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_details_class_details` FOREIGN KEY (`tutor_id`) REFERENCES `employee_details` (`emp_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_courses_offered_class_details` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `courses_offered` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Anyone know why they don't list parent table information? and the way, How we can get the details of foreign key constraints?

**P.S. : storage engine is InnoDB.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `mysqldump` that Oracle has characterized as a "feature request."

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66821

In normal mode (not XML), `mysqldump` just uses the server's output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`.

```
if (!opt_xml ...
    ...
    my_snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "show create table %s", result_table);
```

When running in `--xml` mode, `mysqldump` uses the output from `SHOW KEYS FROM 'tablename'`, which doesn't include the foreign key constraints.

```
my_snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "show keys from %s", result_table);
```

Since the two different operating modes of `mysqldump` fetch the data from the server in such different ways, so the addition of this information to an XML dump is not exactly a trivial change.

There is not a simple workaround, although as noted in the bug report, the information is available in `information_schema` and you can access this from `mysqldump` if you supply the `--skip-lock-tables` option (locking information_schema isn't allowed).  You'll have to take the data you retrieve, parse and extract the relevant bits, and reformat it as needed before it would be all that useful.